# Setup Autofac in .NET Core 3 and 3.1

Tags: c#, autofac

From the [official Autofac documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#startup-class) for ASP.NET Core 3.0 (I am using .NET Core 3.1), the `startup` constructor parameter type in the official documentation is `IHostingEnvironment`

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
  {
    // In ASP.NET Core 3.0 `env` will be an IWebHostEnvironment, not IHostingEnvironment.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    this.Configuration = builder.Build();
  }
```

while mine is `IConfiguration`

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;

        }
```

How do I setup for this method then in .NET Core 3.1? or Autofac has not yet release documentation for .NET Core 3.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two step to setup your autofac in .NET Core3.1.

First,you need to write below in Program.cs.

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
    {
      webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

Then,create a new method in Startup.cs.

```
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("")).AsImplementedInterfaces();
}
```

Comment: With these 2 steps, do I still need to configure and create instance of `ContainerBuilder` at `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: There is no need to create again.Since all your injection is completed at ConfigureContainer.